# How to populate Symfony entities with JSON response coming from remote API

Tags: php, json, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to develop an application that will use data coming from remote API calls. I'd like the data to be saved in a local database so that I do not use up the API's quotes and for easier subsequent retrieval.

I've already set up entity mappings. However, I'm not sure how I should approach the task of mapping the data coming from remote calls (I'm planning on using [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) HTTP client) on the entities and saving them in the database.

With input coming from users, I'd set up `Type` classes and use Symfony's Form Component.

In this case, however, my application will be sending HTTP requests and receiving data that should be mapped and saved.

Should I perhaps first collect the data I need in `DataFixtures`, and then populate my entites from those fixtures?

Another method I thought about was using the FormComponent with the omission of `handleRequest`.

I will also add that I'd like to be able to easily update my local data with the remote data as the remote will be updated on regular basis.

I guess I need a conceptual hint on how to approach this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Form component is a viable solution, additional bonus apart from mapping data to entities is validation. So, you could validate if data is correct before persisting your entities. You can use `submit` method directly:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        // ...
        ->getForm();

    $form->submit(json_decode($yourData, true));

    if ($form->isValid()) {
            // perform some action...

        return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
    }
}
```

Another options is to use serializer's, `deserialize` method:

```
$nameConverter = new OrgPrefixNameConverter();
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, $nameConverter);

$serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array(new JsonEncoder()));

$obj = new Company();
$obj->name = 'Acme Inc.';
$obj->address = '123 Main Street, Big City';

$json = $serializer->serialize($obj);
// {"org_name": "Acme Inc.", "org_address": "123 Main Street, Big City"}
$objCopy = $serializer->deserialize($json);
// Same data as $obj
```

Links:

[serializer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)

[form handling](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/direct_submit.html#cookbook-form-call-submit-directly)

Comment: I think the first option if fit for the task. Another question is what is the best way to pass the the remote API'a response data to `newAction` controller? I guess I should create a service that would talk to the API and utilize it in the `newAction` controller like `$this->get('remote_api_handler')->getData()`. Does that make sense?